# Android Fragment opening another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android development, and situation here is simple: 
There's a fragment that's being called by MainActivity, where the fragment is being replaced with the frameLayout. And now, what I want here is to open up a fragment that contains the detail information from the following onItemClick.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment w = new statDetail();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(w,"detail").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
//From MainActivity
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
// update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (position==0) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, ExpenseFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }
    else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, StatFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Above is the code that I'm trying to accomplish to open up another fragment, but it simply stops the whole program. OnItemClick works fine here, and I have already tried just creating a new activity, but because this uses the pre-made navigationdrawer that android studio provides, pressing back button would come to the first page when I wanted to show up the 2nd page, which I have no idea how to modify. I feel like fragment would be easier to use here, but I really don't know.

In the future, I want to implement the back navigation and would appreciate if anyone can help me solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: It should be your Activity that calls the new fragment not your fragment

Comment: @Kalininskaya So fragment cannot call other fragment? Because I have my listview inside the fragment, and only way to detect the user clicking the listview that's inside the fragment is to just implement the function onItemClick.

Comment: Yes.  And then you need the fragment to tell the activity that user has clicked/selected and then activity loads new fragment.  If you need some help to do this let me know